How to fix flaky test on Playwright?
Hi I have this app that I'm testing. The app itself will fill the value and click the button to provide the data on table. However, in reality it takes more than 40 seconds to load the data itself so when using playwright it has a default of 30 seconds before it timeout. By loading the data, it refreshes the actual app instead just showing the table data values.
What I did:

Use waitforselector for the specific element to load before going to next code
Added the timeout on config to 100 (even though I know this is not a good practice)
Set the test to serialized by setting the parallel run to false
Limit the workers to 1 each test file

I have 8 test cases in total 4 each test files.
This is the code i have:
await page.goto(url)
await page.locator('.txtname').fill(namehere)
await page.focus('.btnsubmit')
await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
await page.waitForSelector('.eid')
await expect(await page.locator('.eid').toBeDefined())

as you can see here i use the focus and enter instead using .click. Why? When I'm using the click event, it always timeout even though i set it to 100 seconds on config but when I come up with the alternative on doing the enter button.
May I know can I still fix the flaky or fail issue on test cases here?
ERROR: Timeout exceeded to 100000MS on waitforselector element / flaky
What I did:

Use waitforselector for the specific element to load before going to next code
Added the timeout on config to 100 (even though I know this is not a good practice)
Set the test to serialized by setting the parallel run to false
Limit the workers to 1 each test file

I have 8 test cases in total 4 each test files.

Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with the full code and the page under test, or a minimal reproduction of it, to get help. Thanks. That said, await expect(await page.locator('.eid').toBeDefined()) doesn't work, and should be await expect(page.locator('.eid')).toBeVisible() or similar. locator().toBeDefined() will throw on every run because there is no .toBeDefined() function on a locator.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77076331/1831456

Try to use 'delay' option of the 'click' event.
await page.locator('.btnsubmit').click({delay: 70});

It may help in your case.

i guess im fine with .press enter since it is fairly working well. what im having issues with is the timeout issue on waitforselector class having late output even though I extended the timeout on config.
