Why is Playwright screenshot timing out with "waiting for fonts to load..."?
Why is the Playwright timing out when taking a screenshot? I'm trying to take a screenshot of the MongoDB login website but it's not taking screenshots and giving timeout errors.
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://account.mongodb.com/account/login");

  await page.screenshot({ path: "mongo.png" });

  await browser.close();
})();

I tried to do the same thing in Puppeteer and it works fine!

did it open the browser and load the page? any console errors found?

@JamesAshok Yes it opened the browser load the page and no error.

Great question, but please share the actual timeout stack trace--the issue here is the goto, not the screenshot. I've clarified your title accordingly.

This is the timeout error: node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
page.screenshot: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:

taking page screenshot
waiting for fonts to load...


@wdwd Hmm, so it is the screenshot waiting for fonts to load? Interesting. That makes sense because a few font requests don't seem to resolve in the network tab. Feel free to update the title accordingly. I assumed it was the goto. I suggest [edit]ing the post with the stack trace. Thanks.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77076331/1831456

For some reason, certain sites fail to fire the "load" event, which is the navigation state that Playwright waits for by default with goto. It's good to see a site that reproduces this behavior.
I generally suggest using "domcontentloaded" (or even "commit") instead of "load", since it's faster and more reliable than "load", and never seems to time out:
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://account.mongodb.com/account/login", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });
  await page.screenshot({path: "mongo.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

For pages that aren't stable before screenshotting, you can use something like this (Puppeteer is easily convertible to Playwright), or wait for a certain site-specific selector or network request to finish. A timeout can also work for temporary debugging, but is usually flaky and discouraged.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure yet why Puppeteer works and Playwright doesn't, and what specific behavior on the page prevents goto from resolving for Playwright (this behavior sometimes occurs in Puppeteer too). Possibly there's a slightly different definition of what "load" means, or some implementation detail that causes Playwright to fail on this particular site. So clearly, it's not just the site's behavior at play here--the library also matters. You might want to open an issue with Playwright, or try a few older versions to see whether the behavior may have changed over time.
Note that @playwright/test also seems to work, strangely enough! I can only reproduce the issue in a non-test script like the one above.
I'll look into it further if I have more time--I'm posting this as a preliminary answer. This is a very interesting question worth a revisit.

Instead of relying on page internals , rely on user facing behaviour like image loaded or table loaded. I have used this approach in actual large projects successfully and I am sure anybody who used Playwright in actual project would agree with it intuitively.

What page internals am I relying on? I think you're missing the point of the question: why does navigation never resolve in Playwright but it does in Puppeteer? The answer is that you need to use "domcontentloaded" to avoid waiting for resources that never show up. User-facing behavior isn't important when you're scraping. I think you're very focused on testing but you may not realize browser automation is also a huge thing for scraping, which does not use @playwright/test or expect() calls, and best practices are very different.
