How do I locally flake Playwright tests
Lately I get a lot of intermittent pipeline failures in Playwright for webkit. I don't really want to spend the time on pushing up to the pipeline to view something I could see on my own computer if only I could reproduce the conditions.
My current solution looks like this (I'm also using nx):

Run while yarn nx run-many -t e2e --output-style=stream --project=webkit --skip-nx-cache; do :; done
Run the same again in a different terminal.
PrayWait.
Review the eventual failure.

What is the optimum way to make my flaky tests fail quickly? Ideally in one script.

What does your typical test script look like? Please share one complete script example code along with config settings.

Also see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77076331/1831456

Is your pipeline config and system settings the same as your local config? Increasing parallelism can increase flakiness in some cases.
