waitForUrl behaviour in Playwright
I am using page.waitForUrl method to wait for desired url. After clicking the submit button, I am trying to wait for url using
page.waitForURL("/my-test-url/v1/foo/") but getting time out error. I see that url is caught in onResponse handler log but some how it is failing to wait.
Am I using the correct method ?
Does waitForUrl checks for only first response url it has received after form submit?
Is these any better way for do this?
Code to perform wait for url::
page.waitForURL("**/my-test-url/v1/**");

code to print all response urls:
page.onResponse(response -> System.out.println("<<" + response.status() + " " + response.url()));

Response:
<<200 https://secured.com/v1/pcs/services/browser/qreq/L/8888 
<<200 https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/in-m/static/common/images/waiting.gif
 <<200 https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/in-m/static/common/html/wait.htm 
 <<200 https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/in-m/static/common/images/wait.gif 
 <<200 https://pentinelapi.com/V1/turl/2.0/qed 
 <<307 https://test-domain.com/my-test-url/v1/foo


This isn't enough to go off of. Please share a [mcve] with the full code and the page under test, or a minimal example of it. Thanks.

BTW, waitForURL waits for the main frame to navigate to a URL. Maybe you're looking for waitForResponse?

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77076331/1831456

@ggorlen Can you please explain what is main frame? Is it the first response received after the page navigation?

Sort of. It's anything that happens on the main page frame, the thing you look at when you're browsing a website normally as a human. Requests are things that the main frame kicks off in the background, pulling data down as you browse around a single page app and interact with it. If you're waiting for the main navigation browser page to be on a specific website URL, use waitForURL. If you're waiting for an async background request to resolve, use waitForResponse. Using waitForURL to listen to API requests is not going to work, even if linguistically it might seem plausible.

@VishalAggarwal that link is irrelevant. This is a Java question about waiting for network responses. When you're providing links and answers, please stick to the same language and topic.

The link is relevant. It happens many times where the actual need/goal of OP is different than what is directly asked as a problem . If you read the answer you will find that the OP was not asking that either but accepted eventually that , that resolved his problem as he was over anaylsing the problem and was moving in the wrong direction.

Core issue OP is facing that when he navigating to a new page , he is getting time out on using waitForURL , which can be resolved using the above link which I shared , as a general stable strategy.

The ultimate user goal here is to verify that the user navigated to an expected page successfully.
